# How can I make rsync transfer files in chronological order?

Tags: shell, rsync

I have a directory structure laid out by date like this:

```
2014/01/01
2014/01/02
...
2014/01/31
2014/02/01
...
```

I have new directories and files that get created every day, and I need to rsync them from one machine to another. But if rsync dies for some reason, I need the earlier files to be transferred before the later ones so there's not a gap in the dates. Is there a way to get rsync to do this, or is there some tool other than rsync that's more appropriate for the job?

Comment: Are the older directories being modified, or are they archives?  It seems like you just want to run rsync for each directory rather than on the entire tree.  That would allow you to control the ordering.

Comment: The directory structure is actually deeper than I described - there's a directory for each hour of each day as well. I suppose I could run one rsync for each hour of each day...

Comment: It seems like this should be a concern even if `rsync` doesn't die; while the `rsync` runs, you will have gaps in the dates if `rsync` is transferring them in non-sorted order.

Answer (score 1):

Try `rsync`-ing the individual directories to their respective target locations on the remote host, using a shell loop:

```
for x in */*/*; do rsync <options> $x user@host:/path/to/$x  ; done
```

Where the `*/*/*` pattern matches path components like `2014/01/01`. Glob expansions are sorted.

Of course, we need some error checking for the case that the `rsync` command dies: the whole reason for doing this. The loop could re-try a failed rsync several times and then give up or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

To start with something basic, maybe something like:

```
ls -1t | while read ff ; do echo "$ff" ; echo ; done
```

This will process the file in reverse chronological (newest first) order.  To run it in chronological order (oldest first) `ls -1rt`.

However your question seems to imply a folder structure like

```
2014/
    01/
        01/
            ...
        02/
        ...
        31/
    02/
        01/
        02/
        ..
        28/
    03/
        01/
        02/
        ..
        31/
    04/
        01/
```

So you would need:

```
ls -1trd ????/??/??/ | while read ff ; do if [ -d "$ff" ] ; then echo "$ff" ; echo ; fi ; done
```

If you want to go deeper to hour divisions then `ls -1trd ????/??/??/` would become `ls -1trd ????/??/??/??/`

Ultimately replace `echo "$ff"` with your `rsync` command, but use this to as a dry run to check the order.  With your structure I'm not sure that the quotes matter too much however I try to use it all the time as it most definitely *does* matter when you are dealing with filenames with spaces in.  I have fallen foul of this enough times myself.

**NOTE:  the command is `ls -1` i.e. the digit one, and not the letter el**

Comment: could someone please explain why this was downvoted so that I can learn as well